# Obtaining crlDistributionPoint from nslX509Cert

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to obtain the crlDistributionPoint extension field from a x509 certificate while listening to the onSecurityChange of the nslWebProgressListener from the SecurityUI of the nslSSLStatus?